# Partial class in PHP like we have in C#

Tags: c#, php, oop

Is there any simple way to have a concept of **partial class** in **PHP** like we have in **C#**?
I've tried to make it possible using different namespace but it couldn't work.

Comment: Why would you want it? ... That's an honest question by the way.

Comment: Could be that you are looking for [traits](http://lv1.php.net/traits)?

Comment: Partial classes are more used for where parts of the class are auto generated (for example, by a form designer, or a ORM system) but what's your use case here?

Comment: Write now I'm having a class which is a kind of messy. I want to add more methods to it but I don't want to mess-up with the existing code.

Comment: +1 for asking a reasonable question.  Partial classes can increase code maintainability by decreasing code clutter.  They can be especially useful as classes grow in complexity over time due to new or changing business requirements.  I certainly wish PHP supported them.

Comment: It's a reasonable question, but class complexity isn't a good reason to support it. I would argue it's a bad reason to support it in C#. Code generation is, however a good enough reason; designers, EF, etc. If your intent is to circumvent "my file is too big", then it's time to refactor the class.

Comment: @Dan: The reason it was added in C# was not "File is too big and I want to avoid refactoring". The reason was that in the form designer a lot of code gets auto-generated, and there was a chance that your hand-written code would get overwritten by the auto-generation of the form designer. The solution was to enable you to create a separate file with your own code so that the form designer could rewrite its own code without messing with yours. The PHP use code could well be the same here, sometimes it's a great convenience to split a class file into multiples.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They don't exist.

If, however, you're trying to implement a code generator for which user-land code could be attached (*following the same use-case as in C#*) then the following *may* be a viable option:

```
class Generator
{
    public function generate(Definition $definition)
    {
        if ($this->shouldGenerateTraitFor($definition)) {
            $this->generateTraitFor($definition);
        }
        $this->generateClassFor($definition);
    }
}
```

Given some implementation like the above, you could then:

```
(new Generator())->generate(new Definition([
    'class' => 'GeneratedClass', 
    'trait' => 'GeneratedTrait',
]));
```

And the resulting code may resemble:

```
class GeneratedClass
{
    use GeneratedTrait;
}

trait GeneratedTrait
{
    // @todo; add "partial" code
}
```

What is important to note about `Generator::shouldGenerateTraitFor` is that if it returns `false`, the trait will *not* be *regenerated*. This could be conditional on whether `GeneratedTrait.php` exists, and is necessary to ensure that when the class is regenerated the hand-written trait code isn't clobbered.

*However*, it could<sup>*****</sup> be much to your benefit to consider [object composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) over this approach.

<sub>***** There are times when I feel that the generated code approach can be cleaner, such as with "entity" types, but that's case-by-case.</sub>

Answer (score 8):

PHP uses Traits for this task:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

They allow you to include class parts from an insulated partial file (a Trait) to different classes that shares its logic and maybe other shared logics (like multiple inheritance)

Comment: I think Extension methods (C#) "are" Traits (PHP). And they are not for "this task".
Traits do not handle this issue: "partial class"-like syntax and semantic in PHP.

You can compare these C# concepts:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods ;
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods
Partial class is a single class defined in multiple files. Trait: definitions that can be used in different classes.

Comment: hello @benaja , for sure, but actually we have not other ways to efficiently mimate multiple inheritance, so Traits in php does both the things